# This command is failing file.createNewFile(); Exception "The system cannot find the path specified."

Tags: java, spring

The problem I have is that I am at a state where I cannot change my code, but I can change my configuration.  I am at the deployment stage.  This command worked at our testing stage.

I hope it is either a configuration problem or a permission problem.

In my properties file I have 
    kea.output=C:/TLA/kea  - I use a / even though it is windows.  Windows has usually allowed that.   I am going to change it to \ to see if that helps.

In my applicationContext.xml file I have

```
`<bean  class="org.xxx.xxx.export.util.FileManager">
    <property name="systemFolder" value="${system.folder}"/>
    <property name="keaOutput" value="${kea.output}"/>
  </bean>`
```

The problem is in FileManager, which is a bean in Spring.
At first I create a file then I run this to create the folders.  This runs successfully.

```
        File file = new File( keaOutput
            + File.separator + EXPORT_RPT_FILE );
        createFolders( keaOutput );

public void createFolders( String folderName ) {
    File folder = new File( folderName );
    if ( !folder.exists() ) {
        folder.mkdirs();
    }
}
```

The next line is:

```
file.createNewFile();
```

I receive this partial stacktrace:

```
java.io.IOException: The system cannot find the path specified
    at java.id.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.file.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at the line above file.createNewFile()
```

I am using Java 6 64 bit and on my dev. computer I am using Java 6 32 bit.

Comment: Get rid of the `exists()` check. `mdirs()` obviously has to do it anyway internally. There's also no point in calling `createNewFile` if you are about to call `new FileOutputStream()` or `new FileWriter().`

Comment: Can you manually create the same file on the OS with same login rights from a command prompt?  For future reference, good idea to embed logging (log4J or others) into your app so you can diagnose on a production system.

Comment: Has `C:/TLA/kea` been created when you get the error?

Comment: Thank you I am going to look into the login rights tomorrow.  I am also going to change the folder name then see if it gets created.  I am trying to duplicate this by changing permissions.